# Internet Explorer 11 having issues with themes (Neve) theme.min.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax-error

I am having issues with a theme that I am using for a redesign of a site. The theme is Neve by Theme Isle. I use the recommended plugins including one by them called Orbit Fox Companion and Elementor pro.

The site is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, even Edge but in IE11 some elements are missing and I showing an error in their theme.min.js.

I reached out to them via wordpress but no answer yet.

Can anyone here figure out what is wrong in this code.

All plugins theme and wordpress are up to date.

The section of the js I pulled out in the code starting with d=new  is where the syntax error is.. but I am not sure how to find it.

Any help would be lovely, I am on a deadline and IE is making me sad!

Reading though posts, disabling the Orbit plugin (which didn't help the java error)  signing up with stackoverflow to see help as this is over my head.

`.constructor)||null==(o=L(r)[ae])?i:W(o)),c=s.unicode,u=(s.ignoreCase?"i":"")+(s.multiline?"m":"")+(s.unicode?"u":"")+(me?"y":"g"),**d=new l(me?s:"^(?:"+s.source+")",u)**,f=void 0===t?he:t>>>0;if(0===f)return[];if(0===a.length)return null===N(d,a)?[a]:[];for(var h=0,m=0,p=[];m<a.length;){d.lastIndex=me?m:0;var v,g=N(d,me?a:a.slice(m));if(null===g||(v=le(M(d.lastIndex+(me?0:m)),`

`d=new l(me?s:"^(?:"+s.source+")",u)`

The page isn't loading fully, and things like menus are not working with their submenus.. images are not the right size on posts..

The missing elements may be a problem with the plugin I mentioned but the rest seems to be due to this error. I believe that as the path to this themes.min.js file is ...neve - assets - header-footer-grid

Comment: Please format the code with right indentation.

Comment: sadly the code is one big lump when I look at it.  I have made progress getting elements to show up by losing some plugins and trying others.  Also found out that Elementor pro doesn't support IE11.  But I am getting some where.  The error still comes up if I run a debugger..but so far the only thing I have left to fix is the menu that has submenus that drop down, but they don't show up in IE.  I hope that isn't caused by the error cause I am not sure how to provide people here with the code in a way they can help.

Comment: IF anyone knows how I can show you the code I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can press `F12` to open DevTools in IE11, and check the `Console` panel, I think you'll find some errors there.

and if you want to pretty the minified code, you can do this:

you can copy the code from the browser to a Editor such as `Sublime Text` or `VS Code`, they all have format plugin to pretty the code.

or you can open your page in Chrome and then press `F12` to open DevTools, and then find the `.js` file in `Sources` panel, and then click this:

[image]

and you will get result like this:

[image]